# libgstvulkan-1.0.0.dylib missing from GStreamer plugins bad on OS X/Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, gstreamer, gstreamer-0.10

On OS X 12.1, with  I'm building an app that is complaining about:
`dyld[12690]: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libgstvulkan-1.0.0.dylib`

I've installed the following with Homebrew:

- [GStreamer 1.18.5 installed form homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gstreamer)
- [gst-plugins-ugly](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gst-plugins-ugly)
- [gst-plugins-base](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gst-plugins-base)
- [gst-plugins-bad](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gst-plugins-bad)
- [gst-plugins-good](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gst-plugins-good)

I've been able to find all the required `.dylib` files so far, except for `libgstvulkan-1.0.0.dylib`, which [should be included](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-vulkan.html) with `gst-plugins-bad` but doesn't appear to be in the Homebrew install.

Questions:

1. what am I missing? why don't I have `libgstvulkan-1.0.0.dylib` on my system and where do I get it?
2. I'd like to know how I can avoid Homebrew and just [install the packages directly](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-mac-osx.html?gi-language=c)   but I don't see how to get the `bad` plugins from that side.   Do I need to build from source?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is there is no `vulcan` dependency in the [homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gst-plugins-bad.rb), thus when building the artifact, there is no `libgstvulkan-1.0.0.dylib` artifact.

I tried to include `molten-vk` for the build and turned on `vulkan` flag, but it has some issue of finding the `vulkan_core.h` (which is already in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/molten-vk/1.1.8/libexec/include/vulkan/vulkan_core.h`).

Local build error:

```
==> meson --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gst-plugins-bad/1.18.5_1 --libdir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gst-plugins-bad/1.18.5_1/lib --buildtype=release --wrap-mode=nofallback -Dintrosp
Last 15 lines from /Users/rui/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gst-plugins-bad/01.meson:
Program g-ir-compiler found: YES (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.70.0_3/bin/g-ir-compiler)
Program glib-mkenums found: YES (/opt/homebrew/opt/glib/bin/glib-mkenums)
Program glib-mkenums found: YES (/opt/homebrew/opt/glib/bin/glib-mkenums)
Program glib-mkenums found: YES (/opt/homebrew/opt/glib/bin/glib-mkenums)
Program glib-mkenums found: YES (/opt/homebrew/opt/glib/bin/glib-mkenums)
Did not find CMake 'cmake'
Found CMake: NO
Run-time dependency opencv found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
Run-time dependency opencv4 found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
Library MoltenVK found: YES
Has header "vulkan/vulkan_core.h" : NO

../gst-libs/gst/vulkan/meson.build:146:2: ERROR: Problem encountered: vulkan plugin enabled, but vulkan.h not found

A full log can be found at /private/tmp/gst-plugins-bad-20220227-60197-31i3hx/gst-plugins-bad-1.18.5/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

Feel free to kick off [a PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pulls) and we can get this forward.